# Generating random coordinates (3D) with constraint

Tags: graphics3d, random

I have been trying to generate random $(x,y,z)$ coordinates (i.e. for 15 ellipsoids) so that they obey following constraints:

- ellipsoid's length is constant,
- ellipsoids do not intersect (fulfilled even when they are tilted),
- $z$ can be adjustable, means that random coordinates can be generated 2D $(x,y)$ or 3D $(x,y,z)$,

however, it appeared as a tough task. I know how to generate 15 random ellipsoids but I do not know how to impose the constraints.

Comment: Similar problem, but not equal: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/159484.

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6300640.

Comment: Are the ellipsoids at arbitrary angles?  If so, you may need to simply define a *sphere* having radius the maximum radius of each ellipsoid, then use traditional sphere-packing algorithms.

Comment: I think you should probably consider acceptance/rejection methods.  E.g. 1) generate a random set of ellipsoids 2) If they meet your constraints, accept them, otherwise reject them and try again

Comment: Do the ellipsoids happen to be rotationally symmetric?